# JPA 2.1 Attribute Converter convert enum still insert int

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

i'm  using spring data jpa with  hibernate as provider.
i'm trying to persist my enums on  varchar(enum.tostring) instead of (0,1,2)
my enum class:

```
public enum MagasinType {
PRINCIPAL {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Principale".toUpperCase();
    }
},
SECONDARY {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Secondaire".toUpperCase();
    }
},
MOBILE {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mobile".toUpperCase();
    }
};
public abstract String toString();
}
```

my converter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MagasinConverter implements attributeConverter           <MagasinType,String>{

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MagasinType magasinType) {
    switch (magasinType){
        case MOBILE:return "MOBILE";
        case PRINCIPAL:return "PRINCIPAL";
        case SECONDARY:return "SECONDARY";
        default:throw new IllegalArgumentException("valeur incorrecte" + magasinType);
    }
}

@Override
public MagasinType convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
    switch (s){
        case "MOBILE": return MagasinType.MOBILE;
        case "SECONDARY": return MagasinType.SECONDARY;
        case "PRINCIPAL": return MagasinType.PRINCIPAL;
        default:throw new IllegalArgumentException("valeur incorrecte" + s);
    }}}
```

my entity

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "MAGASIN")
 public class Magasin extends AbstractEntity {

@Column(name = "LIBELLE", nullable = false)
private String libelle;

@Column(name = "DESCR")
private String descr;


@Convert(converter = MagasinConverter.class)
private MagasinType type;

@Column(name = "LOCATION")
private String localisation;

@Version
private long version;
//getters setters omitted
}
```

my java config : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/480ef7a58cdcc50e7481

my app.properties : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/685eaca98fcba9c33872

and finally my test method : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8bb60fee39a201558e19

please help me on it,  i  want to use @convert new jpa2.1 feature instead of
@enumerated

Comment: So, do you want to use the toString() of the enum, or its name? Your text says you want the toString(), but your code says you want the name. And what's the problem you're facing? What happens, concretely? Also, why don't you post real code, that compiles?

Comment: @JBNizet i implemented a tostring to get the string value, and it works,for example in a log or sys.out.print.
but when i save the entity, first spring create the column as an INT, and the values storred are 1.2.3, i want the tostring value to be storred.
also this is a real code that compiles,
this is my repo  you can check
https://github.com/zirconias/RFID_REWRITE

Comment: No standard class is named `attributeConverter`. Classes always start with an uppercase letter. And your converter never calls toString(): it returns "MOBILE" for the enum MOBILE, and does the same for the other enum members. So if that's what you want, all you need is to annotate the field in the entity with `@Enumerated(STRING)`

Comment: @JBNizet for the attributeConverter it is with A just i missed the a and rewrite it again, thanks for the comment , and this is why i'm trying to follow conventions and standards,
i know that @enumerated(enumtype.string) will work, i already mentioned it.
i'm learning spring and trying to test all new release of java ee7 and jpa 2.1( at least trying my best).
in my next comment i'll post the solution, would you please try to explain it ? i didn't got it but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to put the annotation on the getter and it works.

now i can call the @convert to convert enums to strings and visversa when pulling from database.

the same problem happened  when i added @manytoOne on my class attribute, i got a weired problem, no column was added to the table entity.

but when i annotated the getter. every thing  was ok.
please take a look at my github repo to further infos

https://github.com/zirconias/RFID_REWRITE

Comment: this commit fixed my problem 
https://github.com/zirconias/RFID_REWRITE/commit/9b01c5df9eff402724088bf7aa95c3ee5f5074ee